django-import-export, using the foreign key widget
I seem to be having some issues trying to figure out how to use the ForeignKeyWidget in the django-import-export package. I'm hoping someone here will be able to point out what is wrong with my code. I'm able to export the data I want except for the asset. I would like it to be the name of the asset, but it is exporting the ID.
Here is my models
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} {self.name}"

class report(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_active = models.DateField()
    return_code = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    @property
    def since(self):
        return (datetime.now().date() - self.last_active).days

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.machine} {self.last_active} {self.return_code} {self.comment} {self.status}"

Here is my admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import DateFieldListFilter
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import fields, resources
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from .models import asset, report

class reportResource(resources.ModelResource):
    machine = fields.Field(
        column_name='machine',
        attribute='machine',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(asset, 'name'))

    class Meta:
        model = report
        # fields = ('machine',)

class reportAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("machine", "last_active", "return_code", "comment", "status")
    resources_class = reportResource

admin.site.register(report, reportAdmin)
admin.site.register(asset)


I'm exporting the report data. I would like to have the name of the asset instead of the ID.
I tried following the example provided in the document https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget
But it is still exporting the asset ID instead of the name

It looks fine as you have it and it should work and export 'name'.  Set a breakpoint in ForeignKeyWidget.render() and see what field is being read.

additionally, please use v4 and declare resources_classes = [reportResource]
